# Need a solution for Java Method which returns a string Value to be executed only n number of threads in JVM

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

Java Method which returns string(fileName) is consuming memory internally for few Image operations which cannot be further optimized, lets say consuming 20 MB HeapSpace per method execution.

This method is executing as part of ProcessingImageData and need to return the file name as output to RestWebService caller.

While some n threads are parallel processing which is giving OutofMemory.

To escape from OutofMemory-HeapSpace can you please provide your suggestions like 
 setting only fixed number of threads to execute this method.

```
public String deleteImageAndProvideFile(String inputImage, int deletePageNum){
        // process image
        //find page and delete
        //merge pages to new file
        // return new file Name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an number of tasks but you want to limit the number of threads performing them, use an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool.

The `Executors` class has a helper method for creating what you need:

- `newFixedThreadPool(int nosThreads)` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)).

Adjust the `nosThreads` parameter according to how much memory you want to use.

The `ExecutionService` documentation explains how to use the API ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)).  You submit tasks and get `Future` objects that can be used to wait until a given task is finished.

In your use-case, one of your web requests might submit task to a "global" executor service and then wait for the task to complete.  Alternatively you could design your system so that the processing is done asynchronously with the web requests; e.g. submit a task in one request, and then make another request to see if it has been done yet.

Comment: I think using private semaphore variable inside deleteOmageAndProvideFile might work better since it will protect from calling method from several different thread pools.

Comment: A better solution (to that hypothetical problem!) is to not submit the tasks into multiple thread pools.  If you have a worker thread call `deleteOmageAndProvideFile` which then blocks on a semaphore, the worker thread can't do something else.  So you interfere with the other uses of the thread pool.